# Reference request on sociolinguistical matters

Tags: reference-request, sociolinguistics

I am not linguist, but I am looking for reference on the following matter:

**1.** Social function of language and relation of the function with other functions of language.

**2.** Variability of language on the basis of its sociality.

**3.** Social models of language.

Can someone here suggest some papers or may be some book chapters on the subject?

Comment: Unfortunately, the points you're asking for basically sum up the entire field of sociolinguistics. Can you be any more specific about what you want?

Comment: @Draconis I expect a possibly short,(one or more but not so many) freshman master student level reference with discussion/explanation about social function of language and relation of the social function with other functions of language.  Also the same kind of reference which explains how the sociality of the language changes the language. And last but not least, a reference which considers social models of language.

Comment: Again, what you're asking for is an entire field of study in and of itself. It's like asking for a short summary of chemistry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be impossible to sum up the research on your questions with several articles since you're questions are the central questions of an entire field of study that has been developing for over 100 years. What I can suggest, instead, is a rather good textbook:

> Bell, A. (2013). The Guidebook to Sociolinguistics. Chichester, UK: Wiley.

Comment: Thank you a lot. The good book is a better I was expected, that is actually one of the options I was looking for. If one reads carefully the text of my question in the text of question is mentioned that one of my expectation was a good book of a chapter in a good book. 
I fully understand that the all material of the area can not be contained in one or several papers.  But as you may know usually there are some texts which sum up the development of the area up to some period of time. My question is about such kind of reference.  Am I asking for some miracle as @Draconis describes?